# Make weapon appear on mobile AR camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mobile, augmented-reality

I am using Unity with AR Core and AR Foundation to run a mobile AR game. I want the phone to represent a sword and when the phone tilts or moves the sword also tilts or moves. So the camera is a first person view with a sword coming out.

When I add the sword above the MainCamera it just stays static and when I add the Sword as a child of the MainCamera it doesn't show up.

How do I get a sword to show up and rotate/move with the camera in the first person for AR mobile in Unity?